# How do I Create Custom Drop down that allows multiple selections (like resource selection works)

Tags: ms-project

I have a project that has multiple workstreams.  In much the same way a single task may require multiple people to work on it, it also may touch multiple workstreams.

I created a custom column called workstream with the list of workstreams to choose from but I can only select 1 workstream per task. Is there a way to set it up so I can select multiple workstreams (check boxes rather than just a drop down list)?

Answer (score 1):

Using Project Server, you can create enterprise custom fields that allow multiple values to be selected from a drop-down list. But this option is not available in MS Project.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I was pretty sure I looked everywhere but thought I'd ask. At least I know to stop trying now. Appreciate the "closure"  :-)

Comment: Glad to help. Speaking of closure, can you mark this answer as accepted?